# Unable to change ACF Gallery image size

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I don't know how to change the size of images in my gallery. I've tried putting a class on the images and using css to change the size which doesn't work as the class is just ignored. I've also tried changing the size using thumbnail, medium and large but the image wont grow any bigger than 150px by 150px. How can I change the image sizes and make them responsive?

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <?php 

            $image_ids = get_field('gallery', false, false);

            $shortcode = '[gallery ids="' . implode(',', $image_ids) . '"]';

            echo do_shortcode( $shortcode );

            ?>

            <?php 

            $images = get_field('gallery');

            if( $images ): ?>

                <ul class="row">
                    <?php foreach( $images as $gallery_images ): ?>
                        <li class="col-md-4">
                            <a href="<?php echo $gallery_images['url']; ?>">
                                 <img src="<?php echo $gallery_images['sizes']['medium']; ?>" alt="<?php echo $gallery_images['alt']; ?>" />
                            </a>
                            <p><?php echo $gallery_images['caption']; ?></p>
                        </li>
                    <?php endforeach; ?>
                </ul>
            <?php endif; ?>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Do you have this in a place that can be visually inspected?

Comment: Instead of `$gallery_images['sizes']['medium']` put `$gallery_images['sizes']['gallery-thumb']` OR `$gallery_images['sizes']['gallery-full']`

Comment: thanks but that didn't work the images were still 150px by 150px

Answer (score 0):

You can try adding your own image sizes to your `functions.php`. Here is the manuel: [WordPress add_image_size() function](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_image_size/). You will have to re-upload your images since it wont regenerates the thumbnails automatically.

After that add `class="img-responsive"` to your `img` element which bootstrap uses for responsive images.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT:

According to ACF you can try this:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <?php 

            $image_ids = get_field('gallery', false, false);

            $shortcode = '[gallery ids="' . implode(',', $image_ids) . '"]';

            echo do_shortcode( $shortcode );

            ?>

            <?php 

            $images = get_field('gallery');
            $size = 'thumbnail';                            // Here size Defined (thumbnail, medium, large, full or custom size)
            $thumb = $images['sizes'][ $size ];             // Here Initiate the size you want
            $width = $images['sizes'][ $size . '-width' ];  // Here you can get the specific size
            $height = $images['sizes'][ $size . '-height' ];

            if( $images ): ?>

                <ul class="row">
                    <?php foreach( $images as $gallery_images ): ?>
                        <li class="col-md-4">
                            <a href="<?php echo $gallery_images['url']; ?>">
                                 <img src="<?php echo $thumb ; ?>" alt="<?php echo $gallery_images['alt']; ?>" width="<?php echo $width; ?>" height="<?php echo $height; ?>" />
                            </a>
                            <p><?php echo $gallery_images['caption']; ?></p>
                        </li>
                    <?php endforeach; ?>
                </ul>
            <?php endif; ?>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```